# Using IPSec only for incoming connections in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ipsec

I have a server (WS2016) with two adapters, a different IP assigned on each adapter, but with the same gateway.

What I want to achieve is that all incoming connections to one of the IP must be protected with IPsec (transport mode), whereas all outgoing connections should not attempt to use IPSec (unless the counterparty requests it).

I setup IPSec on one of the adapters using "netsh advfirewall consec add rule" and "action=requireinrequestout".

It works, in the sense that I can only connect to the IPSec IP using IPSec without blocking any outgoing connection.

However my windows event log is full of event code 4653 ("An IPsec Main Mode negotiation failed"), which mostly appear to be for outgoing connections (and actually mostly DNS lookups). Effectively windows is randomly using either adapter for outgoing connections, but when it goes through the IPSec adapter, it tries to establish an IPSec connection with the counterparty, which doesn't work and then switches to a regular connection. This is not a massive problem, but first it is certainly slowing connections and I would rather do the right thing, i.e. having all outgoing connections not attempting to use IPSec.

netsh advfirewall consec does have an action "requireinclearout" however it only applies to tunnel mode.

I tried increasing the metric of the IPSec IP to 1000, and the associated gateway metric to 1000 too. Route print does show the higher metric for the IPSec route, however windows seems to ignore that higher metric and to still send outgoing packets through the IPSec adapter.

I tried setting up static routes specifically for the DNS servers, but windows seems to ignore these static routes and use the IPSec adapter.

So my question is: is there a way to achieve IPSec being used only for incoming connections on a server, but not outgoing connections?

Comment: Why are you overcomplicating this with a second interface and IP? I've worked with several windows ipsec configurations and I've never seen the need. I'm just saying to be careful since it seems you might be falling into the xy problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I have two interfaces for another reason. One of the services I want to expose to the WAN is the file sharing service, however for obvious reasons (not the least SMB2 is not encrypted) I only want to expose it through IPSec. I can turn on and off the file and sharing service by adapter, I can't do the same by IP (or perhaps with a firewall rule). That's why I need two adapters. The reason I need two IPs is that I also want some services (like https or rdp) which are already encrypted to also be accessible from non windows (and therefore non IPSec compatible) devices (mac, ipad, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your comments to clarify I think this will do what you want.

I'm assuming 192.168.1.2 is your protected interface and 192.168.1.3 is your non protected interface.

Create a specialized connection security rule set as follows.

Endpoint 1 should be set to only 192.168.1.2, which should stop any events from being generated on 192.168.1.3.

On this rule require authentication inbound and request outbound.

Assuming SMB is what you really want to protect set the **protocols and ports to TCP 445** for the rule, again to avoid excess noise. This should stop any extra noise from the DNS lookups.

On your firewall rule for IPSEC protection you'd want to have the local IP scope set to 192.168.1.2 and "allow if secure" settings enabled and the local port being tcp 445.

Comment: Thanks! Testing it now, but it looks like a good solution. In fact I probably don't even need two IPs if I can enable IPSec at the port level (didn't realise I could).